# What application do you use to synchronize work directory with ftp directory?

Tags: synchronize

I'd like to poll this question: What application do you use to synchronize the working directory at local PC and remote directory (via FTP)?

I'm kind of bored of using FTP client to transfer each file I edit all the time.

Answer (score 2):

In a simple case you can use `scp` or `ftp` command line programs to write a small command line script that can upload all your files.  I use a bash script that zips up all my files, puts it on my webspace, and unzips the file over ssh.  Although this would be easily done with bash on linux I think that you can do similar with `bat` files on windows.

For a larger web development project, commit the code to a server side source repository and use a tool like [Capistrano](http://www.capify.org/) to deploy it to remote servers which is a powerful and full featured deployment tool for web application of all kinds.

Comment: If you prefer GUIs, there's IQBox FTP: https://code.google.com/p/iqbox-ftp/
Disclaimer: I'm an author. It's Dropbox-like sync for FTP or FTP-SSL. Free and open-source.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably easier to use a network mount if you're going to poke at files on the server directly. You can do that in Linux/OS X (via FUSE+ftpfs), or in Windows (it can map FTP directories as a network drive, IIRC). I prefer sshfs myself since it means one less service exposed to the network.

But I'd agree with the others - a SCM is better in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

I use Subversion to synchronize the local copy of my website (on which I make modifications) with the live copy: whenever I check in a revision, an SVN hook script automatically updates the live site... so yeah, I agree with everyone else who's recommending a source control system (SVN or perhaps Git). It works quite well for me.

One alternative to consider is [`rsync`](http://samba.anu.edu.au/rsync/), a Linux program which is like `scp` but only transfers the files that have changed. And even for those, it uses a diff/patch-like algorithm to only transfer the changed parts of the files. Like `scp`, it normally runs through an SSH tunnel, although there are other modes of operation which are not secure.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its good time to move to subversion, even it is not ftp.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on files directly then perhaps you should check out a text editor that has native support for working with files on FTP sites. UltraEdit (Windows) and BBEdit (Mac) are two of my favs.

Answer (score 0):

ftp upload ought to be dead by now; if you can ssh to the ftp server, scp and rsync -e ssh are much better. there are Windows GUI clients, but I use the Cygwin command line

Comment: do you know some gui win client?

Comment: Google for "windows rsync" and "windows scp"

Answer (score 0):

Although it sounds like the answers so far are sufficient to your needs (the question sounds like you're only uploading changes, not downloading them), the ftp/scp/rsync-based ones are only really suited to one-way synchronization.  If you need bi-directional sync (both uploading and downloading changes), then you'll need to go with either a remote filesystem-based solution or (better, IMO) a proper revision control system, such as git, svn, or cvs.

Comment: do u know some one way (upload) windows gui client?

Comment: Nope, sorry.  I don't do much under Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at some FTP tool that provides visual synchronization. For example, on Windows, Mac, or Linux, you can use CrossFTP to do one-way or two-way synchronization. It supports masks and filters, and you can preview/modify the results as shown in the picture. [alt text http://img509.imageshack.us/img509/9417/picture1t.png](http://img509.imageshack.us/img509/9417/picture1t.png)